# Accessing application deployed on Heroku

Tags: java, rest, heroku

I have deployed my application on Heroku, now I am unable to access the application.

Mine is a restful java application & I have followed the following steps to deploy.

```
heroku login
git clone http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.git
cd project_name
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku deploy:war --war xxxxxxxxxxx.war --app appName
```

After deployment, it gave me back a url like follows:

https://some_context_name.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

Am I supposed to do anything after this? If I am looking for a GET rest call of /v1/xyz, what should be my url?

Comment: Did you follow this to deploy your heroku app ? "https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git". In your case i supposed you didn't config your project as a maven project, if you didn't, you should do that to make sure it works stable with Heroku server.

Comment: yes I have followed steps, I see the app deployed on there, but I am unable to send rest requests, it just doesn't recognize. If my app is deployed at some.heroku.com, how do I access my rest calls ? say I have a request in the form of /v1/x/y/ ?

Comment: Can you go to your IDE and take a photo regarding to the project folder structure and post here and share some code about your API ?

Answer (score 3):

In logs, you can check the ip address at which your app is deployed.

> > heroku logs -n 200

and it will show your url's and ip address.. something like below..

```
enter code her 2017-10-03T17:56:26.280776+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/hello" host=writealone-demo.herokuapp.com r
```

`equest_id=e64e66a1-e1b2-4681-84f7-647cb28b3c28 fwd="150.242.67.234" dyno=`connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`

and you can make your proper url as :

```
protocol:ipaddress/path
```

or  protocol : host/path

i.e.  `https://150.242.67.234/hello` 
or   `https:writealone-demo.herokuapp.com/hello`

Answer (score 1):

Your url should be `https://some_context_name.herokuapp.com/v1/xyz`.

That is the url of the heroku app and added to it the route of your app.

Comment: This is not working for me. if you have any other approach please help me.
Please see my code and question in details here. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884534/unable-to-access-apis-from-heruko-while-jar-is-deployed