# Unable to access API's from heruko while JAR is deployed

Tags: java, api, heroku, jar

**JAR has been deployed to heroku succefully :**

Message from command line:
*remote:    https://minmint.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku*

**My code piece:**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1")
public class Projects {
@RequestMapping(value = "gethelloworld",method = RequestMethod.GET)

public String Hello() {
    return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Now i'm trying to access my api through postman as: [https://minmint.herokuapp.com/api/v1/gethelloworld](https://minmint.herokuapp.com/api/v1gethelloworld)
which was giving me:
Could not get any response.

***Any help will be appreciated and will be very helpful***

Comment: what is the output of `heroku logs`?

Comment: when i try to see logs of Heroku, it keep in loading and haven't shown any log for 10mins.

Comment: The app is probably asleep. Run the command and then open it in a browser

Comment: @codefinger, it was running locally as expected. But not with Heroku.

Comment: Run `heroku ps:scale web=1` and then `heroku logs`. No way to know what’s wrong until you get logs